# how to use grep to output anything between 2 keywords ? RegEx for grep

Tags: grep

I would like to grep a chunk of data from example: `man find`.

I know there is a section of examples in `man find`, it starts with `EXAMPLES` and end with `EXIT STATUS`. Hence i want to grep that specific chunk of data out.

How to do that  with simplest way ? best without using other tools which i might not know how to use yet.

`$man find | grep '\<EXAMPLES ....  '` ?

I find RegEx is very hard to remember and apply.. Anybody has got any trick to it ?
thx

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Your best bet is using `sed`, `awk` or `perl` for this rather than `grep` -- any of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-print-lines-between-two-patterns-inclusive-or-exclusive-in-sed-awk-or) solutions will do. If you really want to use `grep`, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38975890/14722562) answer does just that -- but it requires PCRE anyway.

Comment: @andrew did the above solve your problem? I feel this question is a duplicate of finding lines between two patterns, and as such should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, that answered my question. Thank You costaparas!